# Is that possible to reinstall apache 2 without losing websites content?

Tags: 12.04, apache2

Is that possible to reinstall Apache 2 on Ubuntu 12.04 without losing Vhosts ? as the websites contents are inside.

Regardes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Altough I don't think that uninstalling `apache` will remove the content of `/var/www/`, if you want to make sure that you won't lose anything upon reinstallation do the following:

Backup the content of the `/var/www/` folder before reinstalling:

```
tar pcfz <path_to_backup>/www_backup.tar.gz /var/www/*
```

<sub>*<path_to_backup> = path to where to store the backup;</sub>

This way, after reinstalling, if the content of `/var/www/` has been deleted, you can just restore it from the backup:

```
sudo tar pxf <path_to_backup>/www_backup.tar.gz -C /var/www/
```

<sub>*<path_to_backup> = path to where the backup was stored;</sub>

Notice that the `p` option in `tar pcfz [...]` and `tar pxf [...]` is required to preserve the permissions of `/var/www/`'s content upon backup / restore.

If you don't have physical access to the server, you can backup the content of `/var/www/` through `SSH`:

```
ssh <username>@<host> 'tar pcfz - /var/www/*' > <path_to_backup>/www_backup.tar.gz
```

<sub>*<username> = username on the server; <host> = host name / host address; <path_to_backup> = path to where to store the backup;</sub>

And to restore, if needed:

```
< <path_to_backup>/www_backup.tar.gz ssh <username>@<host> 'tar pxf - -C /var/www/'
```

<sub>*<path_to_backup> = path to where the backup was stored; <username> = username on the server; <host> = host name / host address;</sub>

Comment: Thank you, in fact, I thought than when we install apache on the server, it will remove everything from the server. By the way, is that possible to send this backup file to another server or to download it ? is yes, how please ?

Comment: @BillBird Which method are you going to use in order to do the backup? Can you physically access the server?

Comment: In fact, I have Plesk 11, but when I upgrade from php 5.3 to 5.5, the apache stop to work, I explain this matter here ( http://askubuntu.com/questions/615670/problem-after-upgrading-php-from-5-3-to-5-5-apache-ubuntu-12-04-plesk?noredirect=1#comment867814_615670 ). Now I can access my server only by SSH command

Comment: @BillBird If there aren't security concerns about the content of the virtual hosts (e.g. passwords in plain text within the `.PHP` files) you can just save the backup in `/var/www/`, so that it's accessible through ftp and download it. To restore it you can do the opposite. If there are security concerns about the content of the virtual hosts, save the backup everywhere but `/var/www` and copy it over SSH thorugh `scp`: `scp <your_username>@<host>:<path_to_backup> <path_to_local_backup>` and the reverse to reupload it, `scp <path_to_local_backup> <your_username>@<host>:<path_to_backup>`

Comment: really I appreciatte your effort to support me. I don't know about security issue. I have a dedicated server ( ubuntu 12.04 / Plesk 11 / Apache 2 ) with access by root.

Comment: @BillBird No problem, with security issues I mean for example that if you have any type of script that connects to a database (say a `.php` or a `.asp` file), it will for sure hold a password of the database somewhere within the virtual host. So it's definetly not a good idea to leave the backup accessible through FTP. Also even when not using a database, leaving a backup accessible by anyone exposes the structure of your webapp, and a malicious user might exploit known vulnerabilities in it *way* easier.

Comment: @BillBird So not a good idea unless you have only plain `.html` files. If you are unsure, just go for the `scp` method, it's a little more of a hassle for an unexperienced user but it's *way* safer.

Comment: Ah yes, I have many databases as I'm using .php files, but fortunately I have a copy of all databases on another server. But till now, I hope that your way to do the things with SCP will work through the IP, but when I type the IP in the browser, nothing happen.

Comment: @BillBird Mind that the problem here is not the backup, but the fact that using the FTP method the files would be accessible by everyone who can access the server through a browser. On the other hand, this doesn't apply if your server is not accessed publicly. Have a look at the update on the answer, I added the exact commands to use to backup / restore remotely via `SSH` directly without using `tar` / `scp`. Mind the meaning of the angle brackets, because there are angle brackets that are not to be replaced, replace only the sections mentioned under each command description.

Comment: I'm doing that now and will be back with my feedback soon. Always thank you Kos, you are really very helpful person :)

Comment: tar pcfz <path_to_backup>/www_backup.tar.gz /var/www/* gave me always ( Removing leading `/' from member names ) so I used ( tar -zcvf ). I'm now testing to mave just one website as you advice me, and I will confirm you after.

Comment: @BillBird *You want* `Removing leading '/' from member names` because that saves you from overwriting `/` upon extraction. Also I really suggest you to use the `p` option, because if you change the file's permissions to something different than the group in which `apache` is (e.g. `root` or your user) the files won't be accessible by apache upon restore, and you'll need to run `chmod` to change the owner of all the files inside `/var/www/`.

Comment: everything is OK now ( I sped hours on that issue) I have transfered all data by SCP method as you explained to backup server. The only issue that I still to resolve, is to know is I install now Apache 2.2 again, I will cause a problem for my Plesk ? Till now I can't find a solution to start Apache. Thanks again

Comment: @BillBird Have a read at [this](http://kb.odin.com/en/762), you should be able to update Apache without breaking Plesk.

Comment: Dear Kos, I did everything to save / repair Plesk, but no way. After transfer everything to another server ( content and database ), I restore everything on the master server ( Ubuntu, Apache, Plesk, ...). Someone advice me to replace Ubuntu by CentOS, but I don't know... maybe in the future. Anyway, you made a lot of efforts to help me, and I don't know how can I thank you ? I appreciate really very much your help. By the way, I'm using now ( rsync -av /PathToDirectoy1 root@IP-Server2:/PathToDirectoy2 ) to transfer data from server 1 to server 2.

Comment: @BillBird No problem really, you're very welcome, and I'm glad that I could help you. If you found this answer useful just accept it by clicking the mark under the upvotes count. Also your `rsync` command is fine, altough using compression like in `tar` might save some time. Glad that you somehow solved everything

Comment: I did, thank you again KOS, and a final word to who will read this page ( Question and answer ), I advice you REALLY and after many hours, to use (rsync) to save your work on another server, and restore your master server. Don't lose time to try to discover the real problem with Ubuntu, Apache,... is you are able to move your data ( content + databases ) by (rsync) or as Kos explained by (tar), and restore your server. The most important, you will save YOUR TIME :)